# Order By, Group By in Mongo DB Laravel

Tags: sql, mongodb, laravel-4, mongodb-query

I'm new in Mongo DB and I'm using [jenssegers](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) Library in my Laravel Project.
I have a table called 'table1' which has '_id','c1','c2','c3','created_at' columns. I need to convert bellow SQL query to mongo db.

```
select *, count(c3) as total from
(select * from table1 
where c1 in ('1', '32', '6', ...) 
order by created_at desc) as temp 
group by c2 order by created_at desc
```

I need to select all the column including '_id'. I need only rows containing maximum created_at value by 'order by' when grouped by c2 column and order again result rows by that created_at column.

I found this answer but My question is little bit more complex I think:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24143255/3386509

And this could be useful and related to my problem:
http://blog.chomperstomp.com/how-to-order-by-before-group-by-with-mysql/

Comment: Please make your code more transparent and start each expression in new row.

Comment: Why do you do a GROUP BY when you have no aggregate functions (e.g. MAX, SUM, COUNT)? Also the general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh You're right if hi select 'MAX(created_at)' and 'GROUP BY _ID' then will work, but I don't know MongoDB.

Comment: I have edited my question and added count(c3) and formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

You must use aggregation function see more [mongodb.aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/)

Comment: I think my question was clear, I want to convert that SQL query to mongo db. I searched much more than you gave.