# Get latest row of each group by with Laravel MongoDB

Tags: php, database, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a table called gps in a MongoDB that looks like this:

```
| id | asset_id | coordinates | created_at |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | 11       | 23,-26      | 2018-11-05 |
| 2  | 22       | 33,-36      | 2018-10-04 |
| 3  | 33       | 23,-27      | 2018-11-01 |
| 4  | 33       | 31,-26      | 2018-10-05 |
| 5  | 11       | 23,-46      | 2018-11-02 |
| 6  | 22       | 32,-21      | 2018-11-01 |
--------------------------------------------
```

I am using Laravel and a [Laravel MongoDB Library](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) to use for query building.

My goal is to fetch the latest coordinate of each asset using a group by clause like asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282161/get-most-recent-row-with-group-by-and-laravel) only it will have to make use of the Laravel MongoDB Library mentioned earlier. Another example I tried looking at was [this post](https://medium.com/@akaamitgupta/get-the-latest-record-on-the-group-in-the-most-eloquent-way-50597a588361).

Essentially I should have this returned to me:

```
| id | asset_id | coordinates | created_at |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | 11       | 23,-26      | 2018-11-05 |
| 3  | 33       | 23,-27      | 2018-11-01 |
| 6  | 22       | 32,-21      | 2018-11-01 |
--------------------------------------------
```

I am assuming these examples did not work for me because I do not have access to all the Eloquent functions with this library, only a few basic ones as well as the fact that I cannot use SQL syntax in my query builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by making use of aggregate calls and following [this post here](http://hudsonburgess.com/2017/01/04/mongodb-first-doc-by-group.html).

This is the code I have ended up using although I don't think it is the most Eloquent way possible:

```
$result = GPS::raw(function ($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate([
        [
            '$sort' => [
                'created_at' => -1
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$group' => [
                '_id' => '$asset_id', 
                'gps' => [
                    '$push' => '$$ROOT'
                ]
             ]
        ],
        [
            '$replaceRoot' => [
                'newRoot' => [
                    '$arrayElemAt' => [
                        '$gps', 0
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
DB::table('gps')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->groupBy('asset_id')->get();
```

Comment: This will pull through every record, not the latest of each asset, and won't order it by the created_date so it will not be able to help me.

Comment: This will still pull through every record though, the problem is that I need to order by the created date and group by the asset_id at the same time. However when I try and group by the asset_id, it doesn't keep the order of the created_at columns

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help either, it seems to be merging records together rather than showing all of them as part of a group. I think I need to do something with the raw MongoDB collection. Maybe something like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142931/how-to-convert-mongodb-aggregation-query-to-laravel-mongodb-by-jenssegers)